# Get Nth result of awk

Tags: command-line, text-processing, awk

I am trying to find text between two patterns and it works. But sometimes, I have more than one occurrence, and I would need to get all and use the one I want.

Command example:

```
awk '/>23958742<\/PMID>/,/<\/PubmedArticle>/' file.xml
```

I would like to get all results and see each one separately.
How could I get the Nth match of the command?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us a short extract of the file you are parsing, the output you get and the output you would want to get. The command you are using should print all matches, not only the first, so there's something strange in your input data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel like you're asking two different questions here, so I'm just going to answer both.

#### Get all matches

There's something weird going on here, because the command

```bsh
awk '/>23958742<\/PMID>/,/<\/PubmedArticle>/' <file.xml
```

already *should* output all matches instead of just the first one. There is an alternative though (short and readable version):

```bsh
awk '/>23958742<\/PMID>/{f=1}f==1;/<\/PubmedArticle>/{f=0}' <file.xml
awk '/>23958742<\/PMID>/ {f=1}; f==1 {print}; /<\/PubmedArticle>/ {f=0}' <file.xml
```

#### Get the Nth match

```bsh
awk '/>23958742<\/PMID>/{i++}i==2&&k==1;/<\/PubmedArticle>/{k++}' <file.xml
awk '/>23958742<\/PMID>/ {i++}; i==2 && k==1 {print}; /<\/PubmedArticle>/ {k++}' <file.xml
```

This will simply count the occurences of your strings, save the counts in `i` and `k` and print every line as long as the conditions `i==2&&k==1` are still met. I chose the second block as an example here, for the third it would be `i==3&&k==2` instead. The `k` count comes *after* the conditions because I understood you wanted both the matched lines also to be printed. If you only want what's *between* the search strings turn the whole thing around:

```bsh
awk '/<\/PubmedArticle>/{k++}i==2&&k==1;/>23958742<\/PMID>/{i++}' <file.xml
awk '/<\/PubmedArticle>/ {k++}; i==2 && k==1 {print}; />23958742<\/PMID>/ {i++}' <file.xml
```

I always let the shell open the input file and assign it to the program's stdin (`<file.xml`) because this has a number of advantages, see [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/70759/246819). I found help [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29503988/awk-to-print-nth-instance-of-string) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17908555/printing-with-sed-or-awk-a-line-following-a-matching-pattern).

A general solution proposed by [terdon](https://askubuntu.com/users/85695/terdon) is this:

```bsh
awk -vn=2 '/>23958742<\/PMID>/{i++;k=1}i==n&&k==1;/<\/PubmedArticle>/{k=0}' <file.xml
awk -vn=2 '/>23958742<\/PMID>/ {i++;k=1}; i==n && k==1 {print}; /<\/PubmedArticle>/ {k=0}' <file.xml
```

Using this you just need to set `n` with the `-v` option, e.g. `-vn=2` for the second match.